# matlab set_param function doesn't work in loop

Tags: matlab, user-interface, octave, simulink

I have a Matlab GUI code that lets you draw on axes and passes the coordinates to a constant in Simulink. While the mouse button is held down it should draw on the axes and send the coordinates and when it'not, it should send the coordinates but it should not draw. Here is the code:
`

```
function figure1_WindowButtonUpFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to figure1 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    global bool;
    bool=false;
    set(handles.figure1,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',@(hObject,eventdata)figure1_WindowButtonMotionFcn(hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)));
    %set the WindownButtonMotionFcn back in order to make it work again



function figure1_WindowButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    set(handles.figure1,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',@empty); %change the windowbuttonmotionfcn in order not to let it work
    global bool;
    bool=true;
    global lastX;
    global lastY;
    x=0;
    while bool
        coord=get(handles.axes4,'CurrentPoint');
        if coord(1)<0.003
            coord(1)=0.003
            x=0;
        end
        if coord(1)>1
            coord(1)=1
            x=0;
        end
        if coord(3)<0
            coord(3)=0
            x=0;
        end
        if coord(3)>0.95
           coord(3)=0.95
           x=0;
        end
        if x>1
           arrayX=[lastX coord(1)];
           arrayY=[lastY coord(3)];
           line(arrayX,arrayY);
           set_param('dosya_yukle_deneme/Constant','value',num2str(coord(1)));
        end
        x=x+1;
        lastX=coord(1);
        lastY=coord(3);
        drawnow;
    end

function empty(~,~,~)

% --- Executes on mouse motion over figure - except title and menu.
function figure1_WindowButtonMotionFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    coord=get(handles.axes4,'CurrentPoint');
    set_param('dosya_yukle_deneme/Constant','value',num2str(coord(1)));
```

While the mouse button is pressed down, it draws the lines but the set_param function doesn't work. However, the one in the figure1_WindowButtonMotionFcn works pretty well when needed. It seems like the problem is the while loop. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run your `while` loop within the `figure1_WindowButtonDownFcn` callback because the Matlab GUI is single-threaded. This means the `while` loop  is blocking the Matlab GUI and preventing things from updating correctly. You need to let the callback return in order for Matlab to be able to update the GUI. This is a general rule for GUI callbacks in Matlab; whatever you do in the callback will block the GUI.

In fact you don't need a `while` loop at all, because `WindowButtonMotionFcn` will call back every time the cursor changes. You put the code inside the loop into the `figure1_WindowButtonMotionFcn` callback. You will also need an extra global flag indicating whether the button is down or not, but that is easy to create. `figure1_WindowButtonDownFcn` should set the button down flag, and `figure1_WindowButtonUpFcn` resets the button down flag. Then `figure1_WindowButtonMotionFcn` checks whether the button down flag is set, and if it is, then it executes the code within your `while` loop.

Comment: +1. I'd also add that if one _really_ needed true asynchronous (i.e. multi-threaded) behaviour, one could do this using `batch`. But, agreed, it's not necessary here.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but it works very well actually and I don't really need better performance etc. I'll keep that in mind next time I have to do something like this again.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem! So I found out that the code was working since the beginning. I had connected the constant to a display, while the figure1_WindowButtonMotionFcn was working it showed the value but not while the other one was working. It seems to be that it's a bug in MATLAB UI; the display doesn't renew itself when a mouse button is detected.

Comment: It's not a bug; it's because the while loop prevents the callback from returning. The Matlab GUI is single threaded so if a callback doesn't return, then the GUI gets blocked and does not update correctly - see answer

Comment: @Tom well, it actually works. but at first, I didn't expect it to work either :D